# Reshaping Dataframe using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have the following data in a .csv file:

[Original Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfiWA.png)

I need to reshape the above mentioned data into the following format:

[Required Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwuaE.png)

Can someone kindly explain how can I do that? I have an idea it can be done using df.pivot() function, however, the dates are in the 'headings' of the original format, which is confusing me a bit.

I shall be grateful for the help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, minimal data:

```
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'Province/State':[np.nan], 'Country/region':['Afghanistan'], 'Lat':[0],'Long':[0],'1/22/20':[0],'1/23/20':[0],'6/23/20':[29640]})
print(df)



 Province/State Country/region  Lat  Long  1/22/20  1/23/20  6/23/20
0             NaN    Afghanistan    0     0        0        0    29640
```

Now let us pd.melt this

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Province/State', 'Country/region'], value_vars=['1/22/20', '1/23/20','6/23/20'],var_name='Date', value_name='Confirmed')



 Province/State Country/region     Date  Confirmed
0             NaN    Afghanistan  1/22/20          0
1             NaN    Afghanistan  1/23/20          0
2             NaN    Afghanistan  6/23/20      29640
```

Comment: Minimal advice; For quick answers, please familiarize yourself with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for replying!
I have two queries. First, can you explain what exactly pd.melt() and pd.groupby() does? I was looking at some examples, and these two functions were mainly being used. I have read their documentation but I still have trouble grasping their gist.
Secondly, there are about 160 dates. Is there any way to automatically pick all the dates instead rather than passing them individually as the value_vars argument?

Comment: Thanks for your question. Best bet, look up the documents.Then look up examples of how they are used. Turtorials could also be useful. In such a forum, I cannot exhaustively take you through. For a start pd.melt; https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html .groupby; https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, this code did answer my question! Thank you so much. I have accepted the answer